# LaTeX fails for dollar sign

Tags: mathjax

I am trying to create a latex expression

She owes me \$200 and I owe her $y^2$

But when it is executed, '\$' is converted to '$' but '$y^2$' is not evaluated properly.
Any help is appreciated!

It appears as

[image]

Comment: To the people who vote for close: This does NOT belong to tex.SE, because I think it is a MathJax (JavaScript) problem.

Comment: [I tried this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nBBhX.png) on [math.se], and was unable to reproduce the problem.